# LIMIT LEFT join to last updated row from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

This is my code i am trying to left join the latest team data, not every piece of data. i have tried just using limit 1 but doesnt return anything

ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1

this doesnt work

Any ideas?

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        events.id, events.time,events.status, events.home_team,events.away_team,events.league,
        ht.id as home_id,ht.name as home_name,at.name as away_name,
        statistics.home_goals,statistics.away_goals,statistics.time as game_time,
        leagues.id as league_id,leagues.name as league_name,leagues.type as league_type,
        country.name as country_name,country.logo, 
        hts.home_scored, ats.away_scored, 
        hts.home_conceeded,ats.away_conceeded,
        hts.home_win,ats.away_win,
        hts.home_15,ats.away_15,
        hts.home_25,ats.away_25,
        hts.home_btts, ats.away_btts, 
        hts.home_fts, ats.away_fts, 
        hts.home_cs, ats.away_cs, 
        hts.home_corners_for, ats.away_corners_for, 
        hts.home_corners_against, ats.away_corners_against, 
        hts.home_cards, ats.away_cards
        FROM events 
        LEFT JOIN   teams ht
            ON ht.id = events.home_team
        LEFT JOIN   teams at
            ON at.id = events.away_team
        LEFT JOIN leagues
            ON leagues.id = events.league
        LEFT JOIN country 
            ON country.id=leagues.country
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT team,home_scored,home_conceeded,home_win,home_15,home_25,home_btts,home_fts,home_cs,home_corners_for,home_corners_against,home_cards  FROM team_quick_stats ORDER BY updated DESC)  hts 
            ON ht.id=hts.team
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT team,away_scored,away_conceeded,away_win,away_15,away_25,away_btts,away_fts,away_cs,away_corners_for,away_corners_against,away_cards  FROM team_quick_stats ORDER BY updated DESC)  ats
            ON at.id=ats.team
        LEFT JOIN   statistics 
            ON statistics.event_id=events.id
        WHERE (events.time BETWEEN $start AND $end) ORDER BY country.list_order, leagues.country ASC , leagues.id ASC, events.time ASC, home_name ASC";
```

Comment: What are the values for `$start` and `$end`? Are they strings?

Comment: these are just date values, they aren't strings

Comment: In which case they need to be enclosed in inverted commas

Comment: ok, but this doenst help me haha

Comment: Does the team table only store one row per team?

Comment: (Well, it helps you; it's just not the specific issue cited in the title)

Comment: no, there are multiple rows per team. but with different updated times.

Comment: ah ok, i will adjust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Replace `LEFT JOIN (SELECT team... etc....) ats` with...

```
LEFT
JOIN 
( SELECT x.team
       , x.etc... 
    FROM team_quick_stats x
    JOIN 
       ( SELECT team
              , MAX(updated) updated 
           FROM team_quick_stats 
          GROUP  
             BY team
       ) y
      ON y.team = x.team
     AND y.updated = x.updated
  ) ats...
```